# Ask to rename a misspelled tag [yugabyte-db]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I'm Developer Advocate at Yugabyte. Please can you rename the [yugabyte-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yugabyte-db) tag to [yugabytedb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yugabytedb) as that's the [name](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/faq/general/) of the database.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to match our existing naming conventions of not adding a hyphen when the "DB" suffix appears at the end of the previous word.

Examples: [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb), [couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchdb), [amazon-dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-dynamodb), [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb), [mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mariadb), [innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innodb), [influxdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/influxdb), [indexeddb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexeddb), etc., etc.

I didn't find any counterexamples.  Thus, this is now done.  I also added usage guidance to the excerpt and fixed the spacing there as well.

Comment: [Here's a few hyphenated ones](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*-db%5D&searchOn=3). However, all those either have a name where the "db"/"database" is a separate word, have `-db` used as a way to disambiguate ([tag:sterling-db] seems to do this anyway), or where the source includes hyphenation. Obligatory note that I only checked the wikis, I did not check all the tags, and I did not google to make sure the wiki uses the right name

Comment: The precedent set by other tags doesn't matter. In this case, *the product name* is spelled as "YugabyteDB", without any spaces, so the tag should reflect this. Even though we would normally (grammatically speaking) write "Mac OS" when referring to the OS on Macintosh computers, just as we do for "Windows OS", "Elementary OS", etc., we *don't* because Apple brands it as "macOS". (cc @Zoe)